# Karate Retry Logic and Configuration

Tags: karate

I'm looking for some clarification on the behaviour of `retry until` and karate.configure retry.

When I set a global retry in karate config:
 `karate.configure('retry', { count: 3, interval: 5000 });
 karate.configure('connectTimeout', 5000);
 karate.configure('readTimeout', 10000);`

I would expect this to retry any failing HTTP requests without needing any 'retry until logic/code' on feature level.

When I run the test suite and a request gets read timeouts I don't see the suite running a retry:

2:53:42.491 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out, http call failed after 10008 milliseconds for URL: http://sports/list
12:53:42.495 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - http request failed:

### java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

feature: classpath:features/list.feature

### scenarios: 11 | passed: 10 | failed:  1 | time: 55.7829

HTML report: (paste into browser to view) | Karate version: 0.9.4
file:/usr/src/app/test/functional/target/surefire-reports/features.list.html

Even when I add in `Background:
    * retry until responseStatus == 200` 
in this feature, the test still does not run a retry.

Answer (score 0):

`retry until` comes into play only after a connection has been established and the server is returning HTTP responses. It is designed to handle cases where you need to poll for a particular `responseStatus` or `response` data element.

So it does not cover the case where a connection cannot be established - or what looks like in your case the server taking too long to respond. You may need to increase the `readTimeout`.

Comment: thanks, so is there no way of getting a scenario to retry if it can't connect to the server?

Comment: @NathanGouldman to be honest, no one has ever requested this, typically if you can't connect, all bets are off. also note that the apache-httpclient that is used behind the scenes will re-try 3 times (completely different from karate's retry), so you may see that in the log and it can be confusing. I believe because of that, no one needs any more ways to retry

Comment: What about the situation where the server you're connecting to can be slow for different reasons such as firewalls or it has performance issues? I have come across situations where some endpoints in a server have issues and would cause that test for that to timeout or even fail. And other endpoints were available and more performant.

Comment: @NathanGouldman as I said in my answer, you adjust the timeouts accordingly. note that you can configure the timeouts any time during a test using the `configure` keyword, so you can over-ride what is in config

Comment: Hello @PeterThomas, we were looking to have some tests that run before the main suite, to confirm the environment is up. So after a application deployment, the app might be unavailable for X seconds, we were thinking to handle waiting for the app to be accessible by using retry until (e.g. retry until the healthcheck path returns 200, but at the beginning it might not be connecting at all). And thus we came to this thread! Do you have any suggestions/ideas on this use case?

Comment: @KonstantinosKollias yes ! in 0.9.6.RC4 we have 2 methods on the `karate` JS API called `karate.waitForHttp(url)` and `karate.waitForPort(hostname, portnumber)` let me know if that works: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#karate-waitforhttp

Comment: Awesome, thanks for letting us know! Just tried waitForHttp, and it worked with some caveats. 1) It expects 200, if 200 is not returned then false is returned, caller cannot differentiate if http not available at all, or if it is available and other than 200 was returned. E.g. a healthcheck might be refusing connections as the app starts, but return non 200 until it is fully available to serve requests. Also some people were suggesting we use 204 for our healthchecks. 2) iterations and sleep are not configurable.

Comment: Command used for any future reference: `* eval if (!karate.waitForHttp("http://localhost:7001/health")) karate.fail("myapp is down")`

Comment: @KonstantinosKollias sure. you could use `waitForPort()`. yes it is not configurable but suffices for 99% of use-cases. the code behind it is very simple, write your own Java util if needed. of course, PR-s are welcome :P