# Karate retry mechanism for SocketTimeoutException

Tags: karate

We have a system that we use in order to make some PUT requests during tests. The issue is that this system has, at the moment, some issues with its resources and sometimes it can't answer in time. We can't increase the read timeout to a value greater than 60 seconds for 2 reasons: if the system doesn't answer fast it most likely won't answer at all and secondly we're using a proxy which times out at 60 seconds.

I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60601653/karate-retry-logic-and-configuration) question , but *waitForHttp* or *waitForPort* don't fit our requirements as the port is available and there is no health endpoint telling us if the PUT request will succeed or just be lost.

Is there anything else we can do?

Example feature:

```
  Background:
    * url dep_url
    * configure headers = read('classpath:package/headers/headers.json')
    * retry until responseStatus !== 429

  Scenario: Create entity
    Given request read('classpath:package/body/' + file)
    When path '/entity/' + entity[index]
    And method put
    Then assert responseStatus == 200 || responseStatus == 201
```

We need retries when a SocketTimeoutException is thrown, for example:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out, http call failed after 253 milliseconds for url
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, try polling then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56799845/143475

And combine that approach with the fact that you can use a JS `try-catch` in Karate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67024149/143475

So maybe something like this:

```
* def failed = false
* eval try { karate.call('called.feature') } catch (e) { karate.set('failed', true) }
```

You should be able to figure out a solution now. Do post what you come up with.

EDIT: for those who feel bad about calling a second feature file, you can do everything in one file like this:

```
Feature:

Scenario:
* call read('@called')

@ignore @called
Scenario:
* print 'called'
```

Comment: Peter, is there a way to poll within the same scenario - rather than having to call a 2nd Feature file? I want to add a step to ALL of my feature files to poll to check that there is an open connection to the api. I don't want every feature file to have to be split into 2 files. (This is because wait until doesn't work unless you already have a connection. Basically I don't want any of the scenarios to fail if there is a temporary drop in connection. I want it to retry. But I don't want to have to call features in order to do this.)

Comment: @Matt first let me say the official answer is no. I personally don't understand why people panic when you need to use a second feature file, people do this in programming languages all the time. that said, you can call a scenario in the same feature file (see answer edit). also I think instead of worrying about `retry` maybe the right solution for you is to call a "smoke test" at the start of your suite. karate also has plenty of options for "code reuse", so read the docs. have you looked at `karate-config.js` ? you can do things "globally" there for *every* scenario