# Catch RuntimeExceptions thrown from karate's driver failtures

Tags: karate

Anyone know an appropriate way to catch a RuntimeException thrown from DriverOptions or WebDriver in karate features or outside of them?

Comment: see this answer for a way to do a JS style `try - catch`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71912327/143475